# Scrapy: Failed attempt to download each link in index as full html file

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am attempting to access each link in an index and save the corresponding page in html.  I have attempted to combine the use of LinkExtractor with a full page download --in essence combining these two approaches: [Scrapy-Recursively Scrape Webpages and save content as html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479744/scrapy-recursively-scrape-webpages-and-save-content-as-html-file) and [Download a full page with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233614/download-a-full-page-with-scrapy)

However, I am generating an error pointing to the define parse_item function (line 17).  I believe it has to do with line 18(?).

The parse function works fine when I use it on a single url, but not when I attempt to incorporate it into the LinkExtractor.

My spider.py code is as follows:

```
import scrapy
import urlparse
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class EasySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'easy'
    allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/index.html']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="foobar"]//a/@href'), 
             callback='parse_item')
    )

def parse_item(self, response):
    filename = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)

    return
```

Is this because of a syntax issue or do I need to create/amend the items.py? I am fairly certain I am doing something wrong with the urlparse component but none of the variations I have tried get me passed the error.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: Edit: forgot to close out parenthesis on line 14 on code post...does not affect my question. Apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `parse_item` is not inside the class but outside. So it doesn't become part of your spider

```
import scrapy
import urlparse
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class EasySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'easy'
    allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/index.html']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="foobar"]//a'), 
             callback='parse_item'), 
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
       filename = "index.html"
       with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
           f.write(response.body)

       return
```

Comment: (correcting the obvious mistake I made line 14 in forgetting to use a close-parenthesis...apologies) When I bring the 'parse_item' function inside the class (as you rightfully instructed) it produces a '\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\crawl.py", line 92, in _compile_rules
    self._rules = [copy.copy(r) for r in self.rules]
TypeError: "Rule" object is not iterable' error.  Ordinarily, when I use LinkExtractor, I use 'items' and the exact same syntax for the Rule command, but in this case I want the entire page and I am struggling.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Ran and found the issue, the xpath should only be till the link and not use `/@href`. That scrapy will do for you. Also the `urlparse` was using a `undefined` variable url. So just removed and replaced it with fixed text for now

Comment: Ahh!  I tried dropping both the whole /a/@href...but yes the spider works.  However I get no output. I get no explicit error either.  I try it on `http://books.toscrape.com` with `restrict_xpaths="//*[@class='nav nav-list']/li/ul/li/a" ` and I get : `DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://books.toscrape.com/> (referer: None)`

Comment: That just means the xpath is not leading to links

Comment: `scrapy shell http://books.toscrape.com/` ; `>>> response.xpath('//*[@class="nav nav-list"]/li/ul/li/a/@href').extract()`

Comment: I used `restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="nav nav-list"]/li/ul/li'` and it works for me. Make sure to set the `allowed_domains` to `books.toscrape.com`

Comment: This is my code...[link](https://pastebin.com/BANu2Nkz) I changed the allowed_domains as you instructed.  Is it my restriced_xpath syntax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154410/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-dldatacowboy).

Comment: I was able to get this to work by switching the filename line to `filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'` Thanks for your help Tarun.